# Basis of image of null matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am given the following null matrix of order 3:

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to find the basis of its kernel and its image. To find a basis of its kernel, I need to solve $AX=0$, which should be the span of$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Now, how do I find the basis of the image? From what I've seen I should reduce the matrix in echelon form (which it already is), and pick the columns that are linearly independent. The zero vector is independent to itself so the basis I have for the image is the span of$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

But this won't work because of the dimension theorem:

$$n=dim(ker(A))+dim(Im(A))\rightarrow 3 \neq 3 + 1$$

Or should I pick the columns that have a pivot (in this case no column)? Why? I thought that even though this is a null matrix, we could still generate something by multiplying a vector to it.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Im}(A)=\{0\}$. Also, the span of $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ has 0 dimensions

Comment: Why does it have zero dimensions?

Comment: By definition or convention, $\varnothing$ is a basis for $\{0\}$, so the trivial subspace has dimension $0$.

Comment: "I thought that even though this is a null matrix, we could still generate something by multiplying a vector to it."  But it's null, so everything multiplied by it is $0$ again.  It does not generate something new.

Comment: "*The zero vector is independent to itself*"  Incorrect.  Recall, a collection of vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$ are considered to be independent when the following implication is true: $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_kv_k = 0\iff c_1=c_2=\dots=c_k=0$.  They are considered dependent otherwise if we can find some choice of $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_k$ such that they add to be the zero vector with at least one of the $c_i$ being nonzero.  In the case of the zero vector by itself, notice that $c_10 = 0$ for all values of $c_1$, including nonzero values of $c_1$.  Even alone, the zero vector is dependent.

Comment: To reiterate, for any nonzero vector $v$, you have that $\{v\}$ is an independent set since the only way for $cv = 0$ is for $c=0$.  However, that is not true for the zero vector itself.  $\{0\}$ is not an indepedent set, but rather a dependent set.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone. That makes a lot of sense. Feel free to post your comments as answers and I'll be happy to upvote.